# VIbrancy Continued Extenstion dosen't work in vscode (Mac OS)

Tags: visual-studio-code, macos-ventura

Im using mac os ventura 13.14.1 (c). when i install [Vibrancy Continued](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=illixion.vscode-vibrancy-continued&ssr=false#user-content-FAQs) and hit command+shift+p and Enable it it shows this error[image: here is a picture that shows the error]

i tried setting Color Theme to Dark+ but it still didn't work. im using visual studioi code version Version: 1.81.0 (Universal)
Commit: 6445d93c81ebe42c4cbd7a60712e0b17d9463e97
Date: 2023-08-02T12:40:02.782Z
Electron: 22.3.18
ElectronBuildId: 22689846
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 22.5.0

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).

Comment: I am having the same exact problem. It's really annoying. The folks at vibrancy continued should check that out.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest workaround would be to manually delete the folder specified in the error using Finder, since it seems like something went wrong with that operation (possibly due to permission issues). Just open Finder, press Cmd+Shift+G and copy/paste the path into the "Go To Folder" field

However, this is not a permanent solution and it may have some drawbacks. I think that your question is actually related to a bug in Vibrancy Continued which I maintain. Therefore, I would appreciate it if you could create an issue on GitHub and describe your problem there. This way, I can track the issue, properly troubleshoot it and work on a fix for future releases. You can find the GitHub repository here: https://github.com/illixion/vscode-vibrancy-continued